# Class fields and methods working principle in php

Tags: php, class, methods, properties

I'm trying to assign a function as a property value. I've written the following code:

```
class TestClass{
    private $name;
    public function __construct($name){
        $this->$name=$name;
    }
    public function changeName($name){
        $this->name=$name;
    }
    public function displayName(){
        echo $this->name;
    }
}
$testCls= new TestClass('Dmitry Fucintv');
$testCls->changeName=function($name){
    $this->name='Other name';
};
$testCls->changeName('Some name');
$testCls->displayName();//Display 'Some name', but I'm expected that 'Other name' will be displayed.
```

**Question:** How can I invoke a function which is assigned to a field?

Comment: @olaurendeau This topic is not duplicate. Can you read my question?

Comment: Oops sorry ! I thought you wanted to change her behavior, did you notice your __construct() method is wrong ? it should be $this->name=$name;

Comment: The trick is to "rebind $this", because in your example the new function doesn't know you want it to be part of the object. Note that it still won't have access to any private or protected properties, so this approach is limited in its power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After assigning the function to the property, the object has a *method* called `changeName` and a *property* called `changeName`. Which then does `->changeName()` refer to? Is it `($testCls->changeName)()` or `($testCls->changeName())`? The answer is that the existing method wins out. You cannot overwrite or replace a method this way.

You can call the property function like this:

```
call_user_func($testCls->changeName, 'Some name');
```

However, this will throw this error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

Because `$this` inside the anonymous function you assigned does not refer to `$testCls`, it refers to nothing, since there is no `$this` in the scope where the function was defined.

In other words, this won't work at all the way you want it to.